# Scala sugar for non-generic implicit arguments

Tags: scala

Does Scala provide any sort of syntactic sugar for implicit arguments that do not take a generic type? It would be nice for cases where I don't actually need the argument, and therefore do not care to list out argument names, etc. I'm looking for something similar to

```
def foo[A: Monoid](a: A)
```

but for types such as `ExecutionContext`, which do not have any type parameters.

Comment: You can define a class like `case class WrappedExecContext[A](ec: ExecutionContext)` and use that similarly to `Monoid`.

Comment: Wouldn't that require just as much boiler plate to extract the execution context from it to pass to functions which expect the non-wrapped version?

Comment: I think you are right. I have tried to add an `implicit class` conversion, but it did not look so well afterall. It would require something like: `Implicitly[WrappedExecContext[_]].ctx` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that.

Comment: I doubt there'll be a reference for the absence of a feature, and I have never seen any explanation why.

Comment: There are sometimes mailing list discussions for missing features.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
def foo[A: Monoid](a: A)
```

desugars to:

```
def foo[A](a: A)(implicit m: Monoid[A])
```

If you would like something similar for classes like ExecutionContext, you can use just a plain implicit arg:

```
def foo[A](a: A)(implicit m: ExecutionContext)
```

I am not sure what sugar about this would you like.

Or maybe you actually wanted something different from my understanding.

Comment: Something that lets me just state the type, rather than the `implicit` keyword and having to name the arguments, for cases where I'm just needing the implicit so I can delegate to another method which requires the same implicit.